# How sum a column corresponding to group elements?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a group and in each group there are some individuals. How I can add the value of a column for each person? here is an example:

```
  Group   Person   colum
    1        1       25
    1        1        5 
    1        1       10
    1        2        4
    1        2        8
    2        1        5
    2        1        5
    2        2        20
```

So I want a new column say TOT like this:

```
  Group   Person    TOT
    1        1       40
    1        1       40 
    1        1       40
    1        2       12
    1        2       12
    2        1       10
    2        1       10
    2        2       20
```

Comment: Just do `with(df1, ave(colum, group, Person, FUN = sum))`

Comment: `within` will be better

Comment: @akrun Well, I assumed OP's going to use the following `within(df1, TOT<- ...))`. Doesn't matter much.